# How to view project in Sublime Text

Tags: sublimetext3, preview

I've just completed a beginners course for web development in which cloud9 was used for all coding. It was kind of handy, but it made me realise that whilst I got a decent understanding of a lot of coding theory, I had no idea how to start coding without cloud9! I've downloaded Sublime Text and am creating a web app there. I have everything set up but I have no idea how to find the URL I need to preview my project. Sounds stupid, but I've started the app up with node app.js and it seems to be running, but where do I go now? In C9 there's a preview window with the URL I could just copy over, but I'm a bit lost in Sublime.

Comment: do you physically have to start an app server when coding physically on your local maching? for example rails you need to rails s to start the server, then i just have to open my browser and run localhost:3000 or lvh.me:3000

Answer (score 0):

try localhost:3000 (in your browser window), that's usually the default to preview your app if it's running. I could be horribly wrong as in not overly familiar with app.js.

hope this helps you.